# How to get different places in leaflet map?

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to get places from leaflet but i don't know how to do this, 
for example i want to get restaurants wherever map is centered.
are there any ideas ?

Comment: Search for Leaflet with Overpass API. Restaurants are mapped as `amenity=restaurant` in OSM.

Comment: oh thanks, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find out how to do it ! 
Restaurants are mapped as amenity=restaurant in OSM

thanks to @scai